# An equivalent .split method for hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I need to split a hash based on multiple arguments, which will be keys, and return as an array of hashes.  Basically, I need a method that performs the same job as .split() does for strings, but with multiple delimiters - is there such a thing for hashes?

example:

**Input** 
`({ :a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5, :f=>6 },:c, :e)`

**Output** 
`[ {:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:c=>3, :d=>4}, {:e=>5, :f=>6} ]`

Answer (score 1):

To slice before elements use [`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
{ :a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5, :f=>6 }.slice_before do |e|
  %i[c e].include? e.first
end.map(&:to_h)
```

Generic implementation (without checks):

```
λ = lambda do |hash, *delimiters|
  hash.slice_before do |e|
    delimiters.include? e.first
  end.map(&:to_h)
end
λ.({ :a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5, :f=>6 }, :c, :e)
#⇒ [ {:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:c=>3, :d=>4}, {:e=>5, :f=>6} ]
```

To slice a hash by pieces of the same size, use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
{ :a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5, :f=>6 }.each_slice(2).map &:to_h
```

Comment: I fear he wants to split at keys :c and :e, not each two elements.

Answer (score -1):

With pure ruby (MRI < 1.9) it is not possible to fullfill the task. A ruby Hash has no order of the keys in this versions. So you need  ActiveSupport::OrderedHash which supports an order of keys. In MRI versions >=1.9 it works directly

```
 # in case hs is of type  ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.new
 # ds = delimiters

 result = []
 result_hash = {}
 next_del = delimiters.shift
 hs.keys.each do |key|
   if next_del == key
     result  << result_hash
     result_hash = {}
     next_del =  delimiters.shift
   end
   result_hash[key] = hs[key] 
 end  
 result  << result_hash
 result
```

Comment: You'r right, when you use ruby >= 1.9. My statement is right for ruby < 1.9

Comment: When you refer to the ancient version of the language, please specify this explicitly. After all, this solution is 102% not ruby idiomatic. One should not use ruby syntax to write php code.